# How to watch bootstrap sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, sass

I've downloaded [bootstrap sass](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and put the assets content in my *public/sass* directory. How should I watch changes and update it to a css file. I tried to use the command (in my public/sass directory)

```
compass watch
```

I get the message in my console that "Compass is watching for changes".
When i change something in for example  *public/sass/stylesheets/_variables.scss* I want to generate a .css automaticly in */public/css/style.css* but nothing happens (console dosnt notify for changes). What commands should i use to watch for changes?

My goal is to add some custom classes to the css so I only need to import one css file in my html.

Answer (score 1):

Files prefixed with underscore `_` are ignored by the compiler, since they're 'partials' and are to be used within your Sass architecture through `@import`.

Comment: How should i add custom classes than?

Comment: Assuming you've ran `compass create` you've got a two folders 'sass' and 'stylesheets', all  new files without underscore prefixes within the 'sass' folder like *.scss  will be duplicated and compiled into the *.css in the 'stylesheets' folder. But that's not a good way to do it, you'd rather have one `main.sccs` and a lot of `_partial.scss`, you can then include `_partial.scss` in your `main.scss` using `@import '_partial.scss'`. Then you will have just one compiled *.css file with all your styles. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should also have a `config.rb` file in the directory from which you are running `compass watch`.

In this file you should specify which directory to watch for changes, and the destination directory to write the output.

I'd advise against having your SASS files in /public and have them in another directory alongside, say /stylesheets.

Follow [the Compass config.rb instructions](http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/) to set up your config.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have config.rb.
Config.rb is the glue that connect scss and css stylesheets.